# Finding angle in a square

Tags: geometry

> **Problem**: ABCD is a square, E and F are points on BC and CD respectively such that AE cuts the diagonal BD at G and FG is perpendicular to AE.
>
> K is a point on FG such that AK=EF.
>
> Find the measure of the angle EKF.

#### Progress

So far, I  found that  AG=FG, and that the angle EKF is an obtuse angle.

Comment: I tried and found that AG=FG

Comment: Please, share this info with the community.

Comment: how to share...

Comment: Click on the "edit" button under the question.

Comment: I think the answer is 135 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

as i was unable to draw the picture i uploaded the whole solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $\triangle AKG$ and $\triangle FEK$ are congruent. What is $\angle GKE$?